# How to add values to a newly added column to all existing rows in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to add a new column in to my production database (11g) that has millions of records but need default value only those existing records, meaning no new records should populate this default value.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hopefully you're testing this first, not making changes on your production database on the fly. If the column is not nullable [you can do this quickly in 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-schemamanagement-089869.html), but new records would get the default; but then if it's not nullable and you don't want the default to apply to new records your application is going to always be setting the value, so the default won't apply anyway, right? Otherwise you can update with a default, and then remove the default before any new inserts, which will be slower.

Answer (score 2):

- as per my understanding you want to add column to existing table and update it with default value.

  ```
   alter table table_name add(col_name data_type);

   Update table_name set col_name=some_default_value;
  ```

Comment: By doing this your data not disturbed at the same time default value not continued further

Comment: If we use DML command(UPDATE), will it consume more time to update all the millions of records rather than using DDL(Alter) command itself?

Comment: Ddl alter wont take much time..im not sure about dml update..but instead of giving default value in alter command the above suggested is the best